# TCP > COM1 for receiving messages and displaying on POS display pole

Tags: serial-port, virtual

I currently have a Java Applet running on my web page that communicates to a display pole via COM1. However since the Java update I can no longer run self-signed Java Applets and I figure it would just be easier to send an AJAX request back to the server and have the server send a response to a TCP port on the computer...the computer would need a TCP > COM virtual adapter. How do I install a virtual adapter to go from a TCP port to COM1?

I've looked into [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) and that is just confusing as hell to me, and I don't see how to connect any ports to COM1. I've tried [tcp2com](http://tcp2com.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't seem to install the service in Windows 7 x64. I've tried [com2tcp](http://www.astrogeeks.com/AstroGeeks/COM2TCP/) and the interface seems like it WOULD work (I haven't tested), but I don't want an app running on the desktop...it needs to be a service that runs in the background.

So to summarize how it would work:

- Web page on comp1 sends AJAX request to server
- Server sends text response to comp1 on port 999
- comp1 has virtual COM port listening on port 999, sends data to COM1
- pole displays data

**EDIT:** I'm using Win 7 x64 and tcp2com doesn't work as a service. I tried using srvany but I get an error stating that the application started then stopped. If I use powershell and pass the tcp2com as an argument, it doesn't quit but it also doesn't run. So I nixed the whole 'service' deal and put the command: powershell -windowstyle hidden "tcp2com --test tcp/999 com1" and it works...sort of. The characters that get sent are all effed. I can write "echo WTF > COM1" on another computer which has COM2TCP (different vendor) and it'll come up as a single block on the POS display pole. However if I use COM2TCP on both the server and client machines, everything works fine...but that's only a trial version and it costs several hundred dollars! On another note, is there a way to send the raw text over IP without having to use another Virtual COM > IP adapter on another computer? Sort of like how curl works but different...?

Comment: tcp2com looks like the way to go.  I've looked at the source, and it's pretty straightforward; walk through the registration code and post where it fails.

Comment: See my edits for update.

Comment: OK, *why* doesn't it work as a service?   Does it not install?  Does it not start?

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember at the moment and I don't want to go back and try now that I have a working solution. If I somewhat remember correctly, it was that I was getting an error specifying that it could not find the file...even though the file reference in the registry was correct. I remember getting that kind of error when I tried installing a RoR server and had to resort to srvany.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After somewhat of an exhaustive search, I came across a program called '[piracom](https://pira.cz/show.asp?art=piracom)'. It's a very simple app that lets you specify port settings for the express purpose of connecting a serial port to an listening port over the network. So this is IP > Serial. For Serial > IP I used [HW-VSP3-Single](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html) as even on the piracom website it said it's compatible! I've tested and it works!

I just put a shortcut to piracom in the startup folder of my user account; the app runs off of a .ini that it updates every time you make a change...so if you run the server and hide it, on the next reboot of the pc it'll start up running and hidden with all prior settings. Easy.

Now it's a matter of installing HW-VSP3 on the server and making a method on the Rails app which will write to the virtual COM port. The only issue I can see right now is that writing `echo \14Test This! > COM3` actually prints the \14...if I do that in my Java applet, it sends the "go to beginning" signal.

*Addendum 1: The \14 problem was fixed by using the serialport gem for RoR. I created a method in a controller that returned head :no_content and then send data to the COM port. Calls to this method were made via jQuery's $.Ajax, using "HEAD" HTTP method. Apparently though I had to add the GET verb in Rails routes because the HEAD option isn't supported for some gimpy reason.*

*Addendum 2: Some garbage data was being sent to the display pole at the end of the string...turns out I needed to turn off the "NVT" option in HW-VSP3. Also keep in mind that firewalls need to be modified to allow communication.*